# Garbage value in parent node

Tags: c++, pointers, this, breadth-first-search, sliding-tile-puzzle

I am implementing breadth-first search to solve the 8-puzzle. When I try to create new nodes and point at the current node using the ***this*** pointer the parent pointer returns garbage values. Is this due to iterator invalidation? Is there a way to by-pass this issue, perhaps by using a different container than a vector?

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>       
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:

vector<Node> children;
vector<int> puzzle;
vector<int> goal = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0};
Node *parent;
Node(vector<int> _puzzle, Node *_parent){
    puzzle=_puzzle;
    parent=_parent;
}

void printPuzzle() {
    int count = 0;
    for (auto i: puzzle) {
    if ( count % 3 == 0)
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << i << ' ';
    count++;   
}
}

int findZero(){
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    it = find (puzzle.begin(), puzzle.end(), 0);
    auto z = std::distance(puzzle.begin(), it);
    return (int)z;
}

bool isGoal(){
    bool goalFound = false;
    if(puzzle == goal)
    goalFound = true;
    return goalFound;
}

void moveUp(){
    int zPos = findZero();
    vector<int> temp = puzzle;
    if ( zPos != 0 && zPos != 1 && zPos != 2 )
    std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos-3]);
    Node child = Node(temp, this);
    children.push_back(child);

}

void moveDown(){
    int zPos = findZero();
    vector<int> temp = puzzle;
    if ( zPos != 6 && zPos != 7 && zPos != 8 )
    std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos+3]);
    Node child = Node(temp, this);
    children.push_back(child); 
}

void moveRight(){
    int zPos = findZero();
    vector<int> temp = puzzle;
    if ( zPos != 2 && zPos != 5 && zPos != 8 )
    std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos+1]);
    Node child = Node(temp, this);
    children.push_back(child);
}

void moveLeft(){ 
    int zPos = findZero();
    vector<int> temp = puzzle;
    if ( zPos != 0 && zPos != 3 && zPos != 6 )
    std::swap(temp[zPos], temp[zPos-1]);
    Node child = Node(temp, this);
    children.push_back(child); 
}
};

bool contains(std::queue<Node> q, Node n){
    std::queue<Node> tempQ = q;
    bool exist = false;
    while (!tempQ.empty()){
        if (tempQ.front().puzzle == n.puzzle)
        exist = true;
        tempQ.pop();
    }
    return exist;
 }

int main()
{
std::vector<int> initial;
initial.push_back(3);
initial.push_back(5);
initial.push_back(8);
initial.push_back(1);
initial.push_back(0);
initial.push_back(4);
initial.push_back(2);
initial.push_back(7);
initial.push_back(6);
Node init = Node(initial, NULL);
std::queue<Node> openList;
std::queue<Node> closedList;
openList.push(init);
bool goalFound = false;
while(!openList.empty() && !goalFound){
    Node currentNode = openList.front();
    closedList.push(currentNode);
    openList.pop();       
    currentNode.moveUp();
    currentNode.moveDown();
    currentNode.moveRight();
    currentNode.moveLeft();

    for (auto i: currentNode.children){
        Node currentChild = i;
        if (currentChild.isGoal()){
            std::cout << "Goal Found." << endl;
            goalFound = true;


        }
        if (!contains(openList, currentChild) && !contains(closedList, 
 currentChild))
            openList.push(currentChild); 
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: Don't post snippets - post all the code.

Comment: This is more likely than not, not the relevant code snippet.

Comment: Apologies. I have posted the entire code now.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and reference/pointer are different things. Let's look at one of the problems of your code. Here's problematic code:

```
while(!openList.empty() && !goalFound){
    Node currentNode = openList.front();
    closedList.push(currentNode);
    openList.pop();       
    currentNode.moveUp();
    currentNode.moveDown();
    currentNode.moveRight();
    currentNode.moveLeft();

    for (auto i: currentNode.children){
        Node currentChild = i;
        if (currentChild.isGoal()){
            std::cout << "Goal Found." << endl;
            goalFound = true;
        }
        if (!contains(openList, currentChild) && !contains(closedList,currentChild))
            openList.push(currentChild); 
        }   
    }
}
```

For simplicity let's assume that there's only one Node in openList, and let's call its address **oL0**. Now lets step line by line and see what's happening:

```
Node currentNode = openList.front(); // creates copy of first element in queue
```

As you could've guessed creating copy creates new Node with same inner state. Let's call the address of the currentNode **cN0**. Important thing to remember is that addresses **oL0** and **cN0** are different(they are different objects). Let's move on:

```
closedList.push(currentNode); // creates COPY of currentNode in closedList
openList.pop(); // deletes Node at address oL0
```

Quite simple - closedList has copy of currentNode at address, which we may call **cL0**.

```
// do stuff with currentNode (address cN0)
currentNode.moveUp();
currentNode.moveDown();
currentNode.moveRight();
currentNode.moveLeft();
```

Here lies one the problems. You are changing variable currentNode at address **cN0** (**NOT** the value stored closedList). As we move bit further through your code, into the for loop, we can find out where 2nd problem, your problem, lies. Point of this for loop is to push children of currentNode into openList:

```
for (/* ... */) {
    // ...
    // same problem of creating copies
    if (/* ... */)
        openList.push(currentChild); 
    }
}
```

These children have their parent pointer set to address of an currentNode(which is **cN0**). **At the end of iteration of while loop destructors of all local variables (variables inside while scope) get called, which results in currentNode being destroyed. Meaning that every child Node in openList has invalid address (garbage value you reffered) to its parent.** Beware that same problem appears inside of the for loop.

For ideas how to solve this, I advise looking into [references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), or for example using queues of pointers...